# popup window according to CheckBox checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

If user don't checked, I want to show asp:ModalPopupExtender and get numeric value from this form.

I'm using asp.net wizard control. I don't know "finish" button id. Can somebody help me?

[image]

Comment: Please consider rephrase your question. It means nothing.

Comment: Why don't you know the id of the button? And when do you want to show the popup? After click on *Finish*?

Comment: Because finish button automatically created in asp.net Wizard control. If user don't checked to checkbox and click finish button, i want to show. if checked, there is not problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the target of the `ModalPopupExtender` as a dummy control, i.e., a hidden `Button`, `LinkButton`,... that never is going to be clicked by the user.

The `Wizard` control have a method called `FinishButtonClick`. Here is where you have to check the state of the `CheckBox` and show or not the popup calling to the method `Show()` of the `ModalPopupExtender`. You also can call to the `Click()` method of the hidden control or do it with JavaScript usign the `BehaviourID` of the `ModalPopupExtender`. Your choice.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To get "Finish" button id, just open the page in browser & view the rendered html code **(Right Click -> View Source)**. From their you can get the finish button id.

And after getting "Finish" button id, you can easily associate a Client-Side event to do the required job.

Comment: the id associated to the button change on every rendered, so, that's not the solution